# How can I use Travis for sub directory?

Tags: symfony, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a repo, consisting of some files and a Symfony project in a sub directory.

How can I use Travis build only for the Symfony project in the sub directory of my repository?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify a custom `script:` command to change directory and then build the project. You can place this in your `.travis.yml` to do this:

```
script:
  - cd <sub directory>
  - <build command>
```

Comment: Is `.travis.yml` file with this `script` commands must be placed only at root dir?

Comment: Thanks, it work! But in my case I need to change directory at `before_script` section

Comment: I needed it in `before_install` so that dependencies are installed in the sub directory duing the `install` step.

Comment: I came here with the same problem but had to do some extra reading before I got it to work. Found the solution here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#Package-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: Is there any way to cache this?

Comment: possibly before_cache? I'm trying that and before_install